# JavaScript: Pause a function and wait on a global variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

There is a global variable `window.listNodes` that is an array. This variable is refreshed each 3 seconds and is filled sequentially.

Another function `onOpen()` is triggered by the user and needs to have the global variable `window.listNodes` containing 3 elements, not less. 
What I seek to do: if the global variable has not a `.length` equal to 3 then the program waits that the other part of the code fills  `window.listNodes` and then begin again the function `onOpen()`.

```
socket.onopen = function onOpen() {
        if (window.listNodes.length === 3) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Wait and when window.listNodes.length === 3:
            onOpen(); 
        }
    });
};
```

Is there an easy way to do it? I tried with the function `setTimeOut()` and with a generator function and the keyword `yield` but I failed.

Thank you for your precious help :)

Comment: _I tried with the function `setTimeOut`_ I showed in my answer how this can be accomplished with `setTimeout`. How did you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could use `setTimeout` and a custom interval to wait, for example, 500ms, to do it:

```
function onOpen() {
        if (window.listNodes.length === 3) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Wait and when window.listNodes.length === 3:
            setTimeout(onOpen, 500);
        }
    });
};

socket.onopen = onOpen;
```

Answer (score 2):

With Promises:

```
function getListNodes() {
  return new Promise(function check(resolve) {
    if (window.listNodes.length === 3) { return resolve(window.listNodes); }
    setTimeout(() => check(resolve), 500);
  });
}

socket.onopen = async function() {
  const listNodes = await getListNodes();
  // use listNodes normally
};
```

Within an `async` function, the `await` keyword will pause the function until the Promise it waits for is resolved (or rejected).

The Promise returned from `getListNodes()` will retry the lookup every 500 milliseconds, and resolve if it finds that the length is sufficient.

Take note that natively, `async` functions are only supported in Chrome and in Edge. You will need Babel + Babel polyfill to use them everywhere.