# Wordpress does not recognize JS library

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jspdf

I currently have the problem that I can't manage to import a JS library in wordpress. It is the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library and in wordpress it throws this error message when I press a button. `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jsPDF`
I added this line in functions.php, and also tried it locally.

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jsPDF', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.0/jspdf.es.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jsPDF', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jsPDF.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
```

All other custom scripts I use are working. This is the script by using jsPDF. The script is loaded, I can tell by the console.log before the function.

```
console.log("generate PDF loaded");

function testPDF(){
    console.log("testPDF-function works")
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

    doc.fromHTML($('#a4').get(0), 20,20, {
        'width':500
    });

    doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
```

Comment: So what does dev tools say? Does the file load just fine, but you're simply running your own JS too soon because JS files take time to download, parse, and load into scope?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I get the error message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` when loading the page, but with a path that does not exist. The path is `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-child/scripts/jspdf.umd.min.js.map` Actually, it should take the pad from the internet.

Comment: you can ignore `map` error, those are just from dev tools trying to download the source map (if it exists). Does the .js file itself load? And, when you're in the dev tools console and you type `jsPDF` does it show the correct thing? Because I'm pretty sure you're just not waiting for the `jsPDF` var to exist before you run your own code.

Comment: When I type jsPDF in the console, it returns me an object. [img](https://imgur.com/a/gXLe1Vt)

Comment: In which case you're just running your own code before jsPDF has finished loading. [wait for it to be available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41523950/740553).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the way you enqueue your scripts.

1. The name of the script should be unique.
2. Probably the cause of your error message: You are locating the cdn inside of your plugin folder, which is not the place the file is located.

So your code should look like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jsPDF', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.0/jspdf.es.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'myJsPDF', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/jsPDF.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
```

In your first wp_enqueue_script you had the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, so it was looking for a file inside of your theme folder. But it needs to be only the URL of the CDN.

In The second wp_enqueue_script you give it a unique name, so there will be no conflicts. Maybe have another look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I have included the first `wp_enqueue_script` from you now, the second one was always commented out on my end so there are no conflicts, I just forgot to mention that. But it still does not work, it still comes the same error

Comment: Have you checked if the script is loaded correctly inside of the <head> element of your wordpress website? If it is included and loaded, there might be something wrong with the function. I suggest trying an example of jspdf docu, to make sure it is loaded correctly.  Another important thing: You do load your custom function at the end of your body, don't do?

Comment: I added a code template, which I actually had earlier, but I generated it now without html container. Generating a blank PDF works now, but I'd like to print a container, so I'm reading into html2canvas now, as I've read it works best with that. Thanks for your help.